# insert element in a list and return the same list updated

Tags: prolog

Hi i'm trying to insert an element in a list but it is very important from my program that the result is stored in the original list and not in a new one.
Any code that i have written or found on the internet only succeeds if you create a new list in which the end result is kept.
So my question is can anyone tell me how to define a function: insert(X,L) where X is an element and L is a list?

Comment: If you need to update the list in place, then you're trying to think too imperatively. Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

No, Prolog just doesn't work that way.  There is no such thing as "modifying" a value.  A variable can be unified with a specific value, but if it was already `[1,3]`, it won't ever be `[1,2,3]` later.

Answer (score 2):

As aschepler says, you cannot add or make any change to a proper list, i.e. a list in which every element is already bound.  The only "modifying" we can do is unifying one expression with another.

However there is a concept of a partial list to which additional elements can be "added" at the end.  This is typically known as a difference list, although that nomenclature may not be immediately understandable.

Suppose we start, not with an empty list, but with a free variable X.  One might however think of subtracting X from X and getting "nothing".  That is, an empty difference list is represented by X - X.  The minus "-" here is a purely formal operator; no evaluation of the difference is intended.  It's just a convenient syntax as you see from how difference lists can be used to accomplish what you (probably) want to do.

We can add an element to a difference list as follows:

```
insertDL(M,X-Y,X-Z) :- Y = [M|Z].
```

Here M is the new element we want to add, X-Y is the "old" difference list, and X-Z is the "new" difference (to which M has been added, by unifying the previously free variable Y with the partial list [M|Z], so that Z becomes the "open" tail of partial list X).

When we are finally done inserting things into our difference list, we can turn X into a proper list by setting the "free tail" at that point to the empty list [ ].  In this sense X is the "same" variable as when we first began, just unified by incremental steps from free variable to proper list.

This is a very powerful technique in Prolog programming, and it takes some practice to feel comfortable using it.  Some links to further discussion on the Web:

[From Prolog lists to difference lists]
http://www.irisa.fr/prive/ridoux/ICLP91/node8.html

[Implementing difference lists in Prolog]
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jpw48/difflists.pdf

[Lecture Notes: Difference Lists]
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/lp/lectures/11-diff.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Some prologs provide the [setarg/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setarg%2F3) predicate in order to modify terms in place.

In order to use it over lists, you only need to consider that they are just a nice representation of chains of compound terms with functor `'.'/2`

In any case, when you need to use [setarg/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setarg%2F3) in Prolog, it probably means you are doing something wrong.